# URL Rewriting using web.config

Tags: php, url-rewriting, web-config

I am trying to rewrite URL using web.config but I have no knowledge of it so will you please help me? Below is my web.config code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
                <rule name="xyz" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*"/>
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
                </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I have a url like: http://www.example.com/?file_name=manage_test

I want it to be like: http://www.example.com/manage_test **OR** http://www.example.com/manage_test.html

How can I perform this action?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This rewrite rule will do this rewrite to you:

```
<rule name="xyz" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?file_name={R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This url `http://www.example.com/manage_test` will be rewritten to `http://www.example.com/?file_name=manage_test` and etc.